# Listview on Lightning Component

Tags: lightning, aura, component

I'm trying to create a list view with InlineEditing but the option is not showing up. please see the code listed below, this element is from lightning framework and it includes  " enableInlineEdit="true"

[image]

Comment: r u using in standalone app or lightning APP? what about logging profile access setting on `Account` sobject?